# Loop doesn't work when I call it in Private Sub Change

Tags: vba, excel

I have this long loop written. If I use the code as it is pasted in (1) works without any problem. The loop code basically takes into consideration multiple  columns which have similar text and sums up the total value of the data in another column. As I said, (1) works without any problem.

(1)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim TestRow As Integer

Dim TestColumn As Integer

Dim Sum As Integer

TestRow = Target.Row

TestColumn = Target.Column

    If (TestColumn = 64) Then


        If (TestRow > 11) Then
            Sum = 0
            EColumnValue = 0
            FColumnValue = 0
            IColumnValue = 0
            APColumnValue = 0
            AQColumnValue = 0

            For i = TestRow To 11 Step -1

                If (i = TestRow) Then

                    Sum = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New").Cells(TestRow, 64).Value
                    EColumnValue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New").Cells(TestRow, 5).Value
                    FColumnValue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New").Cells(TestRow, 6).Value
                    IColumnValue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New").Cells(TestRow, 9).Value
                    APColumnValue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New").Cells(TestRow, 42).Value
                    AQColumnValue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New").Cells(TestRow, 43).Value
                Else

                    If (EColumnValue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New").Cells(i, 5).Value) And (FColumnValue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New").Cells(i, 6).Value) And (IColumnValue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New").Cells(i, 9).Value) And (APColumnValue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New").Cells(i, 42).Value) And (AQColumnValue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New").Cells(i, 43).Value) Then
                        Sum = Sum + ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New").Cells(i, 64).Value

                        If (Sum > 100) Then
                            MsgBox "Similar values entered in columns E, F, I, AP and AQ equals more then 100"
                            MsgBox "Please re-enter the correct value in column BL"
                            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New").Cells(TestRow, 64).Value = ""

                            End If
                    Else

                    End If
                End If
            Next

        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Instead if I write the code as in (2) I receive the error "run-time error 424".

```
Sub loopvba()

Dim TestRow As Integer
Dim TestColumn As Integer
Dim Sum As Integer

TestRow = Target.Row
TestColumn = Target.Column

    If (TestColumn = 64) Then


        If (TestRow > 11) Then
            Sum = 0
            EColumnValue = 0
            FColumnValue = 0
            IColumnValue = 0
            APColumnValue = 0
            AQColumnValue = 0

            For i = TestRow To 11 Step -1

                If (i = TestRow) Then

                    Sum = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New").Cells(TestRow, 64).Value
                    EColumnValue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New").Cells(TestRow, 5).Value
                    FColumnValue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New").Cells(TestRow, 6).Value
                    IColumnValue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New").Cells(TestRow, 9).Value
                    APColumnValue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New").Cells(TestRow, 42).Value
                    AQColumnValue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New").Cells(TestRow, 43).Value
                Else

                    If (EColumnValue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New").Cells(i, 5).Value) And (FColumnValue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New").Cells(i, 6).Value) And (IColumnValue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New").Cells(i, 9).Value) And (APColumnValue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New").Cells(i, 42).Value) And (AQColumnValue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New").Cells(i, 43).Value) Then
                        Sum = Sum + ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New").Cells(i, 64).Value

                        If (Sum > 100) Then
                            MsgBox "Similar values entered in columns E, F, I, AP and AQ equals more then 100"
                            MsgBox "Please re-enter the correct value in column BL"
                            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New").Cells(TestRow, 64).Value = ""

                            End If
                    Else

                    End If
                End If
            Next

        End If
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Call loopvba

End Sub
```

The reason why I don't want to use the first code (1) is because in my worksheet I have other VBAs code working based on **Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)**. Henceforth, I google it and I found out that you cannot have more than 1 **Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)** in your worksheet.

How can i make my loop code to be integrated and work with the other vba codes i wrote under **Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)**. I attached a photo below, so maybe is easier for you to understand my question. Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvXhh.png)

Comment: Start with putting Option Explicit at the top of the code and then compiling and see if it flags anything

Comment: Target is out of scope for LoopVBA in version 2. It would need to be passed as an expected parameter to LoopVBA

Comment: You need some `Target Practice` :D

Comment: Yes you cannot have more than 1 `Worksheet_Change` event but you can have multiple conditions in 1 `Worksheet_Change` :) What exactly are you achieve?

Comment: @ Siddharth Rout: I just want to call the vba loop code under "Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)" as I did with the other codes I wrote.. How can I set "Target Practice"? Thanks

Comment: Target practice usually refers to any exercise in which projectiles are fired at a specified target. You do not have to throw projectiles but yes, you have to understand what `target` means here. Why are you using it like `TestRow = Target.Row`? What kind of object `Target` is? What error are you getting? Why are you getting the error that you are getting? What is the meaning of that error? How can you resolve that error? Try debugging the code. This is what I meant by `Target Practice` which I used humorously :) I can give you the code but I doubt you will learn from it :)

Comment: I use TestRow = Target.Row in order to get the last edited Row number no matter what cell is next. Same thing for Test.Column. Yes, i might not learn from it as I just started writing VBA code. All i did until now, was based on logical thinking, and as you can see my vba loop code is pretty simple to read and understand. True is that i don't have the theory knowledge to go behind the meanings. That is why I am asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Target is out of scope for loopvba in version 2. It would need to be passed as an expected parameter.

```
Sub loopvba(ByRef Target As Range)

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'code

    loopvba Target

'code

End Sub
```

Comment: Would you please explain me what "$A$1" stands for? Thanks

Comment: It was an example use case for a cell that changed. I have edited it out. The key part, in relation to the likely cause of the object required error is the lack of Target being available to the sub loopvba.

Comment: So based on what I understood, I put the code like this, but is not working:                  
                                                                                                          
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Application.Intersect(Range("E11:BL10000"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    loopvba Target
End If

Comment: What error message are you getting and on what line? Use F8 to step through. It may be you have other errors which is why Option Explicit is useful.

Comment: Did you also amend the loopvba code  signature to Sub loopvba(ByRef Target As Range)? Step through the code with F8 as there may be more than one problem to resolve.

Comment: If I use F8 and go through the code, I don't get any error. It might be because I am not calling right loop under Private Sub Worksheet_Change... I posted above how i wrote it.

Comment: yes, I did this as well: Sub loopvba(ByRef Target As Range)

Comment: I think this is what I am using it wrong: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Application.Intersect(Range("E11:BL10000"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    loopvba Target
End If